# c# Como se suman varios numeros con una variable string en la misma linea?

Tags: c#

Antes de nada,  solo consigo que se sume en diferentes lineas ( Lo que quiero es que dentro de la linea he poder poner la cantidad de numeros que quiera separados o juntos y que me los sume todos )

Esto es lo que me ha salido de momento, que estoy haciendo mal?.

```
int suma = 0;
        

  

  Console.WriteLine("Di 10 numeros");

    for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Pon el numero {x}");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        suma += input;
    }

   

    Console.WriteLine($"La suma es {suma}");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Si escribo "10 1 44" imprima 55 ?? eso?

Comment: Sip pero ya me han respondido asi q ntp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aca adjunto la manera de realizar lo mencionado en la pregunta.

```
int suma = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Digite los numeros que quiere sumar separados por coma (Ej. 2,4,5,6,9)");

string lineaNumeros = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

string[] lineaNumerosArr = lineaNumeros.Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < lineaNumerosArr.Length; i++)
{
    int input = int.Parse(lineaNumerosArr[i]);
    suma += input;
}

Console.WriteLine($"La suma es {suma}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Bua gracias ya llevaba 1 hora y no me salia, es justo como lo necesitaba :)